# Given list of string find the index in other list

Tags: python, list

I have two list:

```
 items = ['SZ1/SS1', 'ZZ1/ZS1', 'ZS1/SS1', 'ZZ1/SZ1', 'ZZ1/SS1', 'SZ1/ZS1']
 z1_wanted = ["SZ1/SS1", "ZS1/SS1", "ZZ1/SS1"]
```

Given the strings in `z1_wanted` I want to get the index of the strings in `items`,
returning

```
   [0, 2, 4]
```

How can I achieve that?

**Update:** corrected the index

Comment: Your indexing is wrong, shouldn't it be `[0,1,3]`

Comment: The index of `SZ1/SS1` is `0`, not `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension, like this

```
print [items.index(item) for item in z1_wanted]
# [0, 2, 4]
```

You can also use `map` function, like this

```
print map(items.index, z1_wanted)
# [0, 2, 4]
```

**Remember** `index` function will throw an error if the `item` is not found in `items`.

If you want to do the reverse of this, then you can do

```
myid = [1,3,4]
print [items[item] for item in myid]
# ['ZZ1/ZS1', 'ZZ1/SZ1', 'ZZ1/SS1']
```

Comment: Thanks a million, One more thing. Given the list of index how can I return the value? e.g. `myid = [1,3,4]`, I want to get the member of `items`, returning `['ZZ1/ZS1','ZZ1/SZ1','ZZ1/SS1']`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using list comprehension and enumerate:

```
>>> [i for i, j in enumerate(items) if j in z1_wanted ]
[0, 2, 4]
>>>
```